# Trigger an Action When Mouse Enters URL Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I'm designing a lightbox to appear when a user attempts to abandon a website (I work in UX).

Previously we have used a line of JS to say 'if the mouse leaves the window to trigger the lightbox' but this is causing frustrations when users just want to click the back button for example.

I've heard from a UX expert that the lightbox may be triggered to appear only when the mouse hovers over the URL input field in a browser or when it passes over the close button in the top right of the window.

I understand JS but unsure if this is actually possible since it requires targeting locations outside of the window.

Question is, can this be done? If so, does it require any type of code apart from JS/JQuery?

**EDIT**

Since people are down voting this genuine question - I'll add that I don't agree with the content of this I just need to know the possibilities.

Comment: Isn't UX supposed to make the user experience better?

Comment: Those UX Experts should probably give you the sample code and it doesn't sound very user friendly but more a feature users didn't ask for but the business wants?

Comment: Yes but this is a marketing driven exercise, I'm just helping facilitate. Doesn't mean I agree with it!

Comment: I don't think you can attach hover events on browser specific buttons. - As a side note: "I'm just following orders" is usually the main reason software is written badly cause the orders are usually given by people making decisions based on cost rather than what is in the best interest of the user :)

Comment: @Nope I know mate. This isn't the usual piece of work for me. Work politics aside... thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to make a distinction between the user leaving the current page (in the current state) via back button, changing URL, clicking bookmark or just closing browser.

For all else you can use the `onbeforeunload` event.

**But for the sake of your user, please just tell those marketing colleagues that it's not possible.**